# SQL Group by doesn't return a single line result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm trying to write some SQL using Sum, Count, and Group By.

My DB server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

My actual query is quite complex linking multiple tables etc. but I think I have come up with a simple example that demonstrates the problem I'm facing.

What I'm hoping for is a single line of output summarising the records that match the criteria.

This is my test data table

```
ID  Category (Char) Amount (int)    SubCategory (Char)
1   A               10                  X         
2   A               15                  X         
3   A               20                  X         
4   B               20                  X         
5   B               30                  X         
6   C               50                  Y         
7   A               60                  Y         
8   A               70                  Y         
9   B               80                  Y         
10  B               90                  Y         
11  B               80                  Y         
12  C               70                  Y         
13  C               60                  Y
```

This is the SQL I have so far

```
SELECT [Category]
      ,Sum(Amount) as [Amount Sum]
      ,COUNT(Amount) as [Item Count]
      ,Count(Distinct[SubCategory]) as [SubCategory Count]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTable]
Where Category = 'A'
Group by Category,[Subcatagory]

Select * from TestTable
```

My desired result is this

```
Category    Amount Sum  Item Count  SubCategory Count
A           175         5           2
```

However my result comes out like this

```
Category    Amount Sum  Item Count  SubCategory Count
A           45          3           1
A           130         2           1
```

I'm at a bit of a loss for what else to try, any ideas?

Comment: Remove `,[Subcatagory]` from  group by and it should work

Comment: It's a **category** (not a *catagory*) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` only by Category:

```
SELECT [Catagory]
  ,Sum(Amount) as [Amount Sum]
  ,COUNT(Amount) as [Item Count]
  ,Count(Distinct[SubCatagory]) as [SubCatagory Count]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTable]
Where Catagory = 'A'
Group by Catagory
```

Comment: I can't believe how simple that was and how close I was.  Thanks for answering my question.  I'll go and see if I can figure out how to apply this to my actual problem. :)